# ECMAScript equality: Is null of Type Object?

Tags: javascript, equality

I am trying to implement the algorithm described in [ES262,  The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-11.9.3). It states:

> 1. If Type(x) is the same as Type(y), then
>
>    a. If Type(x) is Undefined, return true.
>
>    b. If Type(x) is Null, return true.

So when we perform the comparison:

```js
console.log(null == {})
```

it should evaluate to true, because null and {} have the same type. Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: in javascript the expression (typeof null === typeof {}) evaluates to true

Comment: `typeof null` being `object` is actually a bug and not an intended feature. No one fixed the bug because of backwards compatibility issues

Comment: I just checked and you are correct

Comment: https://2ality.com/2013/10/typeof-null.html#:~:text=In%20JavaScript%2C%20typeof%20null%20is,it%20would%20break%20existing%20code.

Comment: Also by this logic `null == { foo: 'bar' }` should also be true

Comment: `Type()` in the spec is **not the same as `typeof`.** `null` **does** have its own *internal type*, Null, just [`typeof` returns `"object"` for it, too.](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-11.4.3)

Comment: Just because 2 instances have the same type, doesn't mean they are the same instances.

Comment: @FZs I believe that should be an answer to this question

Comment: In [the specs](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/) If you look at section 6 where it describes the types used in JavaScript you'll notice that there is a `Null` type (6.1.2) and an `Object` type (6.1.7).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it should evaluate to true because null and {} have the same type and x is null,

This is your mistake.

- `null` is of [the Null Type](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-8.2)
- `{}` is of [the Object Type](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-8.6)

The types are different.

Comment: I think my mistake was to assume that typeof operator behaves in the same way like the Type() operator used in the documentation.